# Which latch should I get to replace the one on my front (storm) door?

Tags: doors, exterior, lock, replacement, latches

The locking mechanism on my front (storm) door got broken, rendering it useless. What I’d like to do now is replace the latch with a new one, but I can’t find any branding on the door, so I’m not sure what to get. Here are some pictures of the door and the latch. I’d like to know what would make a suitable replacement. Thanks
[image: the door]
[image: the latch from inside]
[image: the latch from outside]
[image: the latch with the plate off]

Comment: If you take the mechanism to a good locksmith they may be able to tell you whaat the mfgr is and even sell you the mechanism. The locksmith may even know how to repair the faulty mecchanism.

Comment: Look in the frame for a sticker. Or top or bottom or sides of the door. Take the face plate off and turn it over. Take it all, all the way out and look at it.... I can feel that hardware though the picture; it's awesome; get it fixed, not buy some BS from china.

Comment: I'd dump the whole lockset.  The finish is well past the best before date.  That just looks like a mortise door lock set.  Door company's don't typically make their own hardware so you should be able to replace it.